# Handling Click event on a certain component of a composite WinForms UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, user-controls

I develop a WinForms `UserControl` in C#.
The `UserControl` is essentially a composite control that consists of several child controls, e.g. a `PictureBox`, a `CheckBox`, a `Label`, etc.

From the calling code, I want to be able handling a `Click` event for my control.
However, I want the event raised if and only if  the user clicks on a certain component of my control, e.g. the `PictureBox`. If the user clicks anywhere else within my control, the event should not be raised.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using WinForms.

You should delegate a `Click` event from a pictureBox **into your own event** and then subscribe to it from the calling code.

```
public class MyControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    // Don't forget to define myPicture here
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    // Declare delegate for picture clicked.
    public delegate void PictureClickedHandler();

    // Declare the event, which is associated with the delegate
    [Category("Action")]
    [Description("Fires when the Picture is clicked.")]
    public event PictureClickedHandler PictureClicked;

    // Add a protected method called OnPictureClicked().
    // You may use this in child classes instead of adding
    // event handlers.
    protected virtual void OnPictureClicked()
    {
        // If an event has no subscribers registerd, it will
        // evaluate to null. The test checks that the value is not
        // null, ensuring that there are subsribers before
        // calling the event itself.
        if (PictureClicked != null)
        {
            PictureClicked();  // Notify Subscribers
        }
    }
    // Handler for Picture Click.
    private void myPicture_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        OnPictureClicked();
    }
}
```